# Use --name-only option with GitHub API diff media format

Tags: github-api

I am trying to use the GitHub API V3 diff media type to retrieve a list of changed files between HEAD and a specific commit.  I only want the filenames.

Essentially I want to do:
`git diff HEAD <commit> --name-only`

I have been partially successful by sending a GET request to

`https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repos>/commits/<sha>`

with the following 'Accept' header:

`"application/vnd.github.v3.diff"`

However this gives me the full diff.  Is there a way to retrieve only filenames?

The documentation I have consulted is https://developer.github.com/v3/media/#commits-commit-comparison-and-pull-requests

Answer (score 0):

I just found documentation on the 'compare' resource at the following link:
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits

It seems that instead of using the diff media type I can simply request from the following URL:

`https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repos>/compare/<sha>...master`
and then query the "files" and then "filename" fields on the response.